# ExecuteNonQuery is returning Random numbers instead of returning actual rows

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have stored procedure which takes xml as an input .

The C# code to execute the SP is

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Configure_Users", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var xmlData = new SqlParameter(parameterName: "@XMLDATA", value: GenerateXML(_userDetails));
        command.Parameters.Add(xmlData);

        count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return count;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException  )
    {

    }
}
```

The method GenerateXML returns a string which is in the form of xml data .In my stored proc i have removed SET NOCOUNT ON to return me the actual no of rows when inserted ,deleted or updated .If i run my query with the sample xml data :-

```
<UserCollection>
    <InsertList><Users User_Id="438"  First_Name="Praveen"  Middle_Name=""  Last_Name="Kumar"  Designation_Id="1"  Email="" Contact_Number="96533"  Updated_By="pkumar"  />
    </InsertList>
    <UpdateList></UpdateList>
    <DeleteList></DeleteList>
</UserCollection>
```

The value returned is 3 instead of 1 as in my collection im passing only a single row  which needs to be inserted .Since there are no rows which are updated or deleted .How can the SP return 3 when it has to return only 1 ??

The stored Proc is

```
  set ANSI_NULLS ON
  set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   go



  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Configure_Users]
@XMLDATA xml
  AS
 DECLARE @Users_Staging Table(
[User_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[First_Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[Middle_Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
[Last_Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[Designation_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Email] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[Contact_Number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Updated_By] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
  )

  BEGIN

  Set nocount off
  Go    

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION


  DECLARE @CurrDate datetime;
  SELECT @CurrDate = GETDATE();
   -- Insert statements for procedure 
  INSERT INTO Users
  ([User_Id]
  ,[First_Name]
  ,[Middle_Name]
  ,[Last_Name]
  ,[Designation_Id]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Contact_Number]
  ,[Updated_By]
  ,[Updated_Date]
  )
  Select    
XMLDATA.item.value('@User_Id[1]', 'int') AS User_Id,    
XMLDATA.item.value('@First_Name[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS First_Name,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Middle_Name[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS Middle_Name,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Last_Name[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS Last_Name,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Designation_Id[1]', 'int') AS Designation_Id,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Email[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Email,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Contact_Number[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Contact_Number,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Updated_By[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Updated_By,
@CurrDate
  FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//UserCollection/InsertList/Users') AS XMLDATA(item)

  -- Update statements for procedure 

  INSERT INTO @Users_Staging
       ([User_Id]
  ,[First_Name]
  ,[Middle_Name]
  ,[Last_Name]
  ,[Designation_Id]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Contact_Number]
  ,[Updated_By])

Select  
XMLDATA.item.value('@User_Id[1]', 'int') AS User_Id,    
XMLDATA.item.value('@First_Name[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS First_Name,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Middle_Name[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS Middle_Name,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Last_Name[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS Last_Name,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Designation_Id[1]', 'int') AS Designation_Id,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Email[1]', 'varchar(250)') AS Email,
   XMLDATA.item.value('@Contact_Number[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Contact_Number,
XMLDATA.item.value('@Updated_By[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Updated_By
  FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//UserCollection/InsertList/Users') AS XMLDATA(item)


  UPDATE Users 
  SET First_Name=stgusr.First_Name,
  Middle_Name=stgusr.Middle_Name,
  Last_Name=stgusr.Last_Name,
  Email=stgusr.Email,
  Contact_Number=stgusr.Contact_Number,
  Updated_By=stgusr.Updated_By,
  Updated_Date=@CurrDate
  FROM Users usr INNER JOIN
  @Users_Staging stgusr
  ON usr.User_Id=stgusr.User_Id

-- Delete statements for procedure 

   DELETE Users
   WHERE User_Id
     IN (Select         
    XMLDATA.item.value('@User_Id[1]', 'int') AS User_Id
FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//UserCollection/DeleteList/Users') AS XMLDATA(item))

   COMMIT TRANSACTION;

   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
--EXEC sp_rethrow_error;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH; 
   END
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code for the stored procedure.

Comment: @Joe, perhaps not impossible  :). Praveen: please revise your title; it's highly unlikely that a random number would be returned.

Comment: The question has been updated

Answer (score 1):

If you have triggers on the tables updated/inserted by your stored procedure, they will affect the affected row count:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.
>   [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Suggest you post the stored procedure, and schema/triggers for the tables involved.

Comment: It seems to me that if i pass only one row for insertion as an xml input ,the SP is returning me 3 even if there are any rows for updation and deletion . I have posted the code for SP

Comment: Finally i found the solution . There was a mistake in my stored Proc . While updating the table i was taking the value from InsertList instead of UpdateList from the XML input .               

    FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//UserCollection/InsertList/Users') AS XMLDATA(item)

It should be

     FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//UserCollection/UpdateList/Users') AS XMLDATA(item)

Sorry for wasting all your time guys .Just found out how important is to do unit test :)